# cyclic dependency ... how to solve?

Tags: c++, dependencies, circular-dependency

I think I have a cyclic dependency issue and have no idea how to solve it....
To be as short as possible:
I am coding something like a html parser.
I have a main.cpp file and two header files Parser.h and Form.h.
These header files hold the whole definitions... (I'm too lazy to make the corresponding .cpp files...

Form.h looks like this:

```
//... standard includes like iostream....

#ifndef Form_h_included
#define Form_h_included

#include "Parser.h"
class Form {
public:
    void parse (stringstream& ss) {

        // FIXME: the following like throws compilation error: 'Parser' : is not a class or namespace name
        properties = Parser::parseTagAttributes(ss);

        string tag = Parser::getNextTag(ss);
        while (tag != "/form") {
            continue;
        }
        ss.ignore(); // >
    }
// ....
};
#endif
```

and Parser.h looks like this:

```
// STL includes
#ifndef Parser_h_included
#define Parser_h_included

#include "Form.h"

using namespace std;

class Parser {
public:
    void setHTML(string html) {
         ss << html;
    }
    vector<Form> parse() {
        vector<Form> forms;

        string tag = Parser::getNextTag(this->ss);
        while(tag != "") {
            while (tag != "form") {
                tag = Parser::getNextTag(this->ss);
            }
            Form f(this->ss);
            forms.push_back(f);
        }
    }
// ...
};
#endif
```

Don't know if it is important, but I'm doing the build in MS Visual Studio Ultimate 2010
and it throws me 
'Parser' : is not a class or namespace name

How to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Solution: Don't be so lazy ;)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: :-) So it means I must separate the definitions and the declarations? Will it help?

Comment: @Tomy: Yes, without separation it is pretty much impossible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok, I may have said it wrong - I was taught that doing it separately is not tht important so I decided that I won't do it... I didn't know it is crucial to do that... until now I was only doing very simple projects so I didn't need to make separte files...

Comment: @Tomy: It's not "crucial", but it's very wise. This is one of the reasons why. Whoever taught you that it's "not that important" was silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably want to do here is leave the method declaration in the header like so

```
class Form {
public:
    void parse (stringstream& ss);
// ....
};
```

And define the method in a source file (i.e. a Form.cpp file) like so

```
#include "Form.h"
#include "Parser.h"

void parse (stringstream& ss) {

    properties = Parser::parseTagAttributes(ss);

    string tag = Parser::getNextTag(ss);
    while (tag != "/form") {
        continue;
    }
    ss.ignore(); // >
}
```

That should resolve the cyclic dependency issue you're seeing...

Comment: rewrote the classes, issue solved. Thanks. Anyways, I've got one last question: in Parser.h I have one declaration that uses form [vector<Form> parse();] How to resolve that? I tried to write "#include "Form.h" " before the class but it didn't help... Finally I resolved it with "class Form;" before the Parser class. Is there a better solution? Or is this the only one?

Comment: I mean this: imagine I have another inline function in Parser.h "void DO() {Form::DODODO();}" this throws an compilation error - how to resolve that?

Comment: Define `void DO()` in a source file similar to how `parse()` is defined in a source file in my answer above, and that problem goes away, too.  Inline methods with dependencies like (i.e. `Parser::DO()` makes a call to a method defined in `Form`) are a bad idea anyways...

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop defining your member functions lexically inline in headers. Define them in source files.
2. Now you can take advantage of forward declarations when you need them (you don't here).